# Two different fields for GenericRelation in one model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have one model with generic foreign key for several models in my project, which define images for these models:

```
class GenericImage(models.Model):

    image = ImageField(
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(
        'content_type',
        'object_id'
    )
```

I want provide two different links to this model, one with `GenericRelation` for main image and one `GenericRelation` for other images.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    images = GenericRelation(
        GenericImage,
    )
    main_image = GenericRelation(
        GenericImage,
    )
```

The first thing that comes to mind is add boolean field `main_image` to `GenericImage` model and override `clean` method:

```
class GenericImage(models.Model):
    ...

    main_image = models.BooleanField(
    default=False
    )

def clean(self):
    obj = self.content_object
    if self.main_image and obj:
        if obj.images.filter(main_image=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError('main image must be unique!')
```

But it separate validation logic from main model and I'll have to change that boolean field every time when I want to change `main_image`.
Is there any elegant solution for my problem or I don't need `ContentType framework` at all, `m2m` link with intermediate table will be better.

Comment: Use ForeignKey for `main_image` and M2M for `images`